# Creating App bundle file for Desktop Bridge Application -

Tags: uwp, bundle, manifest, desktop-bridge, app-bundle

I am trying to create an app bundle file to upload my file for a release to the Microsoft store. Currently I have a UWP app, Desktop Application and a Packager project to connect the two. I am trying to create the bundle file through the Packager Project and this is the binding point for the UWP and Desktop Application. 
When I try to create the bundle file I am first associating it with the store and then creating the packages. The app is successful in Associating it with the store. When I try to create the bundle file the process just goes on but does not create the bundle file and just stops without any errors. Please can anyone suggest what is this due to and why is it not creating the bundle file?

Do I have to create two bundle files? One for UWP and the other for the Desktop? If I try to create the bundle file for only the UWP app it gets created successfully but my desktop application functions does not seem to work.

Also is there any architecture changes I would need to do?

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to create two bundles, one build with the UWP and Desktop app within the packaging project should be enough.

You say the process stops without errors, check the output window for errors that might not be showing up in the error window.

I would suggest checking out the [Packaging](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-Packaging-Samples) samples which also has a link to an informative blog post on how to make these scenarios work.

Comment: thanks. The output window shows error for my UWP project. Following is the error:The OutputPath property is not set for project 'Please check to make sure that you have specified a valid combination of Configuration and Platform for this project. Configuration='Release' Platform='AnyCPU'. This error may also appear if some other project is trying to follow a project-to-project reference to this project, this project has been unloaded or is not included in the solution, and the referencing project does not build using the same or an equivalent Configuration or Platform

Comment: The UWP project cannot use 'AnyCPU', make sure you are building the package with x86\x64\ARM

Comment: Thanks, I have made all 3 projects including UWP, Packager, desktop(x86) to x86 configuration including one class library and still I am not able to generate the upload bundle file using create Package wizard. Can you please help me in  to create the bundle file for my project? Also, for your information, recently I had created bundle file for my UWP project successfuly and now I have added new features to the UWP project that is the main reason to add desktop project and Packager project in my VS project but I am unable to generate the bundle file to be uploaded on the Microsoft Store.

Comment: What is the error you receive when trying to create the bundle?